# Change numbering into double stepper with angular

Tags: angular, angular-material, stepper

I tried to print stepper into stepper:

```
<mat-vertical-stepper>
        <mat-step *ngFor="let step of Steps" [label]="step.name">
          <mat-vertical-stepper>
            <mat-step *ngFor="let substep of step.subnames" [label]="substep.subname">
            </mat-step>
          </mat-vertical-stepper>
          </mat-step>
    </mat-vertical-stepper>
```

It works but I would like to change numerotation:

change

> - 1
>
>   - 1
>   - 2
> - 2
>
>   - 1
>   - 2

into

> - 1
>
>   - 1.1
>   - 1.2
> - 2
>
>   - 2.1
>   - 2.2

How to do this, please?

Comment: <mat-step *ngFor="let substep of step.subnames" [label]=`${step.name}.${substep.subname}`>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

[EXAMPLE DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-stepper-access-class)

**style.css:**

```
.mat-vertical-stepper-header .mat-step-icon, .mat-vertical-stepper-header .mat-step-icon-not-touched {
  font-size: 0px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    background-color: black;
    height: 5px;
    width: 5px;
}
.mat-vertical-stepper-header .mat-step-icon, .mat-vertical-stepper-header .mat-step-icon-touched {
  font-size: 0px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    background-color: black;
    height: 5px;
    width: 5px;
}

mat-step-header[ng-reflect-selected="true"] .mat-step-icon{ 
  font-size: 12px;
  align-self: center;
  color: white;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
}
mat-step-header[ng-reflect-selected="false"] .mat-step-icon .mat-icon{ 
 display: none
}
```

HTML:

```
<mat-vertical-stepper>
    <mat-step *ngFor="let step of Steps; let i= index;" [label]="step.name">
        <mat-vertical-stepper>
            <mat-step *ngFor="let substep of step.subnames; let j = index" label="{{i+1}}.{{j+1}}">
            </mat-step>
        </mat-vertical-stepper>
    </mat-step>
</mat-vertical-stepper>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works too, is it possible to have index number into the bubble?

Comment: thanks but it seems index numbers are not into the bubbles, maybe it is not possible?

Comment: Do you want numbers as well?? Every thing is possible

Comment: in the first version, there was bubble1 :1, bubble 1 : 1.1, bubble 2 : 1.2...
I would like bubble 1, bubble 1.1, bubble 1.2.. using stepper bubble

Comment: the image you shown in question i have done same thing. if you want something more ??

Comment: Let's try other words: in this example, https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/overview there is "bubble1 Fill out ", bubble1 means "number 1 circled", is this possible to have index numbers as 1.1 circled like this?

Comment: Do you want it for all bubbles or only selected one??

Comment: something like last url, grey bubble if unselected and blue if selected, but if it is not too much? I asked this question because I thought it was only a parameter question...

Comment: Thanks, you helped me a lot and I learned a lot too :)
If you come in Paris, I'll buy you a drink ^^

Comment: @Pim92 thanks for your complement. I will let u know if will be there.

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript syntax inside bind expression

```
<mat-step *ngFor="let substep of step.subnames" [label]="[step.name,substep.subname].join('.')">
</mat-step>
```

or just

```
[label]="step.name + '.' + substep.subname"
```

But it's slow down performance for large menu because it requires calculate expression every time angular do "dirty check" (if you don't use onPush strategy).

So think about adding `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` for menu component, or precalulate full submenu label before using.

Comment: Thanks, it works, is it possible to have number into the bubble?